# Windows 8 App: Playback MPEG-2 Stream with Audio

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a DLNA device that is giving me an MPEG2 stream with Dolby Digital Plus Audio. I realize that Windows 8 doesn't natively have MPEG2 support, but once you install the WMC add on it works fine. The Video app plays back the MPEG 2 stream with audio just fine.

However when I load the same stream into the media element in my app like this:

```
var stream = await channel.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
me.SetSource(stream, channel.ContentType);
me.Play();
```

(where channel is a StorageFile) it only plays Video. How do I get it to also play the audio part of the stream?

Thanks!